# Simplifying Boolean algebra... What am I missing?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm reviewing boolean algebra, but I'm having trouble with a basic simplification:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
 &x'z'+ xyz +xz'\\
  &= z'(x+x')+xyz\\
  &= z'+xyz\\
  &= ??? \\
  &= z'+xy
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

I can't seem to find a theorem or postulate that satisfies the final step in any table. What is it that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

\begin{eqnarray*}z'+xyz
& = & z'(1+xy) + xyz \\
& = & (z'+z)xy + z'\\
& = & z' + xy
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but where does the `1+xy` come from?

Comment: $1$ stands for $True$ and for any Boolean variable $b$ you have $1+b = 1$ and $1b=b$. The use as presented in my answer is a standard trick in Boolean algebra.